# solve for a constant value?

Tags: approximation

Can we solve for $g$ when $\varepsilon$ is small?

$\newcommand{\sinc}{\operatorname{sinc}}$
$$3\sinc\left(-1+ \frac\varepsilon T \right)-3\sinc\left(1+\frac\varepsilon T\right)-\sinc\left(-3+\frac\varepsilon T\right)+\sinc\left(3+\frac\varepsilon T\right) = \frac\varepsilon g$$

I am not able to get a constant value for $g$. Can one do this?

Comment: If $\epsilon/T$ is small then it might work to expand every $\mathrm{sinc}$ term in Taylor series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\operatorname{sinc}$ is an even function, for $\epsilon=0$ the left side is zero.  Is $\epsilon$ supposed to be small?  If so, we can use $\dfrac d{dx} \operatorname{sinc}(x)=\dfrac {x \cos x-\sin x}{x^2}$ so you can evaluate the first-order Taylor expansion. The first term will contribute $3\dfrac \epsilon T (- \cos 1+\sin 1)$ as will the second.  You get $6\dfrac \epsilon T (- \cos 1+\sin 1)+2\dfrac \epsilon {9T} (- 3\cos 3+\sin 3)=\dfrac \epsilon g$  The epsilons divide out and you can invert both sides to find $g$

Comment: Thanks Michael, shouldn't it be -2/9T? Actually, I know the final answer for g should be 3/16 but I cannot get it!!

Comment: $g$ has to be proportional to $T$ because the left side is all $\frac \epsilon T$ and the right side just has $\epsilon$ You also have the trig functions, so it shouldn't be that simple.  Please use parentheses when using the divide slash. Is the $T$ in the numerator or denominator?

Comment: Yes, g is 3T/16. And, the above answer with the correction of -2ϵ/(9T) and also using the normalized sinc instead of the regular one gives the correct g = 3T/16.

Comment: But what about the terms $\cos 1, \sin 1, \cos 3, \sin 3?$

Comment: By using normalized sinc(x)=sin(pi*x)/(pi*x), those terms become cos(pi), sin(pi), etc.

Comment: Ok, if your sinc includes the factor pi.  It doesn't always.